# I've sent ether from testnet to mainnet but didn't receive anything. Why?

Tags: transactions, testnets

A few days ago I made a transaction at an address known to me (tx made from testnet to global main net). The transaction took place and received over 6 confirmations. The next day this transaction was no longer in the list of committed transactions. The Ether did not reach the destination address (in main net), but they did leave my address (in testnet).

Link to [the transaction on etherscan](http://testnet.etherscan.io/tx/0x80ecde140c6f0d1419db4ae71db1f9aa7f43be24feaab332f85ac6d516e846f2).

Why has the destination address still not received Ether?

I understand about can't transfer ethers from testnet to any other net.
Thanks to all for help...

Comment: On Etherscan it says the recipient has 150 ETH. Are you sure your node is fully synced?

Comment: Here's the recipient on etherscan http://testnet.etherscan.io/address/0xc2a2c4df47a4fef4a023139fb570d42ebbcf3512, seems to be fine.

Comment: All accounts already synced(sender and receiver). But destenation address still don't receive ethers.

Comment: So... I think we get little miscommunication. Becouse i send ether from a testnet to main net to 0xc2a2c4df47a4fef4a023139fb570d42ebbcf3512 and this recipient(in main net) don't receive ethers. Why?

Comment: Oh, you can't make a transaction from the testnet to the mainnet... They're separate networks.

Comment: Oooo thanks.Ok. But i can send it(and you see link in first post). Finaly i understand what happen: Now we have two same accounts in two separated nets 1 acc (0xc2a2c4df47a4fef4a023139fb570d42ebbcf3512) in testnet and 1 acc (0xc2a2c4df47a4fef4a023139fb570d42ebbcf3512) in mainnet. Is it possible? Is it not a bug?

Comment: It is not a bug. You simply sent ether to an account that no one really has (on the testnet). Luckily, testnet ether doesn't really have any value. But yeah, it's important to keep in mind what network your accounts are on

Comment: @MrChico Understand, i just want test how it works(send ether from testnet to mainnet). But now it is not possible.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Ether between testnet and mainnet can't be transferred: they are separate networks.

But you need to be aware and **careful of [replay attacks](https://ethereum.stackexchange.com/q/26/42)** if an attacker can see what you're doing on the testnet and has the private keys to the accounts being used.

Also, you can spend the testnet Ether you received (at 0xc2a2c4...) since you already have the private key for it: private keys don't know anything about the network.

Comment: If an attacker has your private keys, they don't need replay attacks to do nasty things to you...

Comment: Upvoted.  Not sure how to improve the answer and thought it's useful to mention replay attacks as a danger when using multiple networks.

Answer (score 6):

Testnet and mainnet are two seperate networks. You can not send Ether from testnet to the mainnet, or in general, you can not transfer anything between the different networks.