# Ethereum Hard Fork: what happened to legacy Ether?

Tags: ether, forks

I currently run Forked Ethereum via Parity. I'm assuming my Ether from *before* the fork is available on this chain. However, does it also still exist on the Ethereum Classic chain? I tried researching this and saw something about how you had to 'split' your Ether across chains, which only confused me more.

The reason I'm asking is Poloniex just added ETC - Ethereum Classic, and now I'm wondering whether my Ether persisted on both chains and can now basically be sold twice if I run both chains (on separate computers). Which seems somewhat strange. Can anyone weigh in?

Edit: [apparently it's true](https://twitter.com/Poloniex/status/757069127018315777) - would still like some more info on this.

Comment: I'm just waiting for the rise of The DAO Classic, or DAOC. :-)

Answer (score 4):

Ether is in both chains.

If you start making transactions from both chains, you need to be very careful of replay attacks.  See
[What is a replay attack?](https://ethereum.stackexchange.com/questions/26/what-is-a-replay-attack) and
[How to prevent a replay attack between two competing chains?](https://ethereum.stackexchange.com/questions/7267/how-to-prevent-a-replay-attack-between-two-competing-chains)

For example, if you give someone legacy Ether without doing any precautions, they can replay that transaction and obtain that same Ether on the hard fork chain.