# How to conditionally send ethers to another account post-hard-fork to protect yourself from replay attacks

Tags: go-ethereum, transactions, hardforks, replay-attack, ethereum-classic

The DAO contract was attacked on 17th June 2016 where the attacker drained about [USD 50 million worth](https://ethereum.stackexchange.com/questions/6408/how-many-ethers-have-been-drained-through-the-recursive-call-attacks-on-the-dao) of ethers using a [recursive call vulnerability](https://ethereum.stackexchange.com/questions/6176/what-is-a-recursive-calling-vulnerability) in The DAO contract code.

The attacker drained the stolen ethers into a few child DAOs and the Robin Hood Group drained the remaining funds into other child DAOs.

The Ethereum blockchain was [hard-forked](https://blog.daohub.org/ethereum-dao-hard-fork-likely-on-july-20th-9ee8e2c12619#.n2dxc12e8) in block [#1,920,000](http://etherscan.io/block/1920000) on 20th July 2016 to transfer the ethers from The DAO contract and it's child DAOs into a [WithdrawDAO contract](http://etherscan.io/address/0xbf4ed7b27f1d666546e30d74d50d173d20bca754#code).

While the majority of Ethereum nodes clients are running the hard-forked blockchain (ETH), a minority of Ethereum nodes clients are running the non-hard-forked Classic blockchain (ETC).

Ethereum node clients can be configured to use the hard-forked blockchain or the non-hard-forked blockchain. Some nodes have been configured to relay the transactions from the hard-forked blockchain to the non-hard-forked blockchain, and vice versa. Transactions executed on the ETH blockchain have a high likelihood of being replayed on the ETC blockchain, and transactions on the ETC blockchain have a high likelihood of being replayed on the ETH blockchain.

Several split contracts have been deployed at the same contract address on both the hard-forked and non-hard-forked blockchains.

How do you use these split contracts to conditionally send ethers to another accounts in either the hard-forked ETH chain or the non-hard-forked ETC Classic chain?

---

### The DAO Refunds

- [How do I convert my The DAO tokens into ethers using the withdrawal contract after the hard fork?](https://ethereum.stackexchange.com/questions/7204/how-do-i-convert-my-the-dao-tokens-into-ethers-using-the-withdrawal-contract-aft)
- [How do I get a refund for the amount I paid in excess of 1 ether to 100 The DAO tokens](https://ethereum.stackexchange.com/questions/7265/how-do-i-get-a-refund-for-the-amount-i-paid-in-excess-of-1-ether-to-100-the-dao)
- [How do I get a refund for my The DAO tokens that was split into a child DAO?](https://ethereum.stackexchange.com/questions/7299/how-do-i-get-a-refund-for-my-the-dao-tokens-that-was-split-into-a-child-dao)
- [How do I convert my The DAO tokens into ethers on the Ethereum Classic chain?](https://ethereum.stackexchange.com/questions/8338/how-do-i-convert-my-the-dao-tokens-into-ethers-on-the-ethereum-classic-chain)
- [THIS] [How to conditionally send ethers to another account post-hard-fork to protect yourself from replay attacks](https://ethereum.stackexchange.com/questions/7396/how-to-conditionally-send-ethers-to-another-account-post-hard-fork-to-protect-yo)

Comment: Related: http://ethereum.stackexchange.com/questions/7267/how-to-prevent-a-replay-attack-between-two-competing-chains

Comment: Don't see any difference in this two threads.

Comment: I am not a solidity expert, but how an attribute became a method ?

Comment: @XavierCombelle: A public state variable, like `forked`, gets an automatically generated accessor method in Solidity.

Comment: @eth I understand, That looks like a bad design of solidity if it tries to be inspired by python: it blatantly violate explicit is better than implicit motto

Comment: @XavierCombelle I don't think Solidity tries to be like Python (the motto is violated in other places like `msg` and `tx` variables).  Feel free to ask questions and welcome to the site!

Answer (score 13, accepted):

**Update Jun 02 2017**

> From [WARNING: Do NOT Use SafeConditionalHFTransfer! Or Use It Correctly](https://www.reddit.com/r/ethereum/comments/6er78h/warning_do_not_use_safeconditionalhftransfer_or/):
>
> The **SafeConditionalHFTransfer** saved a lot of ethers being moved incorrectly on the wrong chain after The DAO hard fork. So far there has been 20549 txns + 16022 internalTxns passing through the **SafeConditionalHFTransfer** at [0x1e143b2588705dfea63a17f2032ca123df995ce0](https://etherscan.io/address/0x1e143b2588705dfea63a17f2032ca123df995ce0#code). The author contacted me this morning about 67,317.257581981046981598 ETH ~ USD 14,892,596.89 (@ $221.23/ETH) sent incorrectly to the contract.
>
> When using this contract, you have to call the `classicTransfer(...)` or `transfer(...)` functions to direct your ETH or ETC to the intended chain. If you send ETH (or ETC) DIRECTLY to the contract address, your ETH (or ETC) will not be redirected to the destination address on the destination chain, but will instead be trapped in this contract FOREVER.
>
> As the recent clients on both the ETH and ETC chains have [EIP155 Replay Protection](https://github.com/ethereum/EIPs/issues/155) built in, you do NOT have to use this `SafeConditionalHFTransfer` any more. Just make sure you are using a recent client, with EIP155!
>
> Here are the main clients and the versions implementing EIP155:
>
> - `geth` Go Ethereum - EIP155 since [Let There Be Light (v1.5.0)](https://github.com/ethereum/go-ethereum/releases/tag/v1.5.0) Nov 16 2016. Latest release [Hat Trick (v1.6.5)](https://github.com/ethereum/go-ethereum/releases).
> - Parity - EIP155 since [Civility (v1.4)](https://blog.ethcore.io/announcing-parity-1-4/) Nov 07 2016. Latest release from https://parity.io/parity.html or https://github.com/paritytech/parity/releases
> - MyEtherWallet (remember to use the right URL https://www.myetherwallet.com/) has EIP155 replay protection.
>
> This warning has also been placed at the top of the answer to [How to conditionally send ethers to another account post-hard-fork to protect yourself from replay attacks](https://ethereum.stackexchange.com/questions/7396/how-to-conditionally-send-ethers-to-another-account-post-hard-fork-to-protect-yo).

---

**Update Nov 26 2016** - See @eth's answer to the question above as `geth` 1.5.3 has implemented replay attack protection.

---

## Summary

- Use Method 1 below if you want to use `geth` to transfer ethers to the hard-forked **OR** non-hard-forked Classic chain via the `SafeConditionalHFTransfer` contract.
- Use Method 2 below if you want to use `geth` to transfer ethers to the hard-forked **AND** non-hard-forked Classic chain via the `ReplaySafeSplitV2` contract.
- Use Method 3 below if you want to use the Ethereum Wallet to transfer ethers to the hard-forked **OR** non-hard-forked Classic chain via the `SafeConditionalHFTransfer` contract.
- Use Method 4 below if you want to use the Ethereum Wallet to transfer ethers to the hard-forked **AND** non-hard-forked Classic chain via the `ReplaySafeSplitV2` contract. Either account can be your source account so that funds are sent back to your account on one of the chains.
- The methods above rely on some Ethereum nodes relaying the transactions from the hard-forked chain to the non-hard-forked chain, or vice versa. If transactions stop being relayed to the other network, the transaction will only be executed on the chain your Ethereum node transmits on.
- **WARNINGS**

  - Transfer a small test amount first
  - If you want your transactions executed on both chains, transfer only amounts that do not exceed your account balance pre-hard-fork.
- **ISSUES**

  - If you transfer an ether amount that exceeds your account balance on one of the chains, the transaction will be rejected on that chain but executed on the other chain. This will cause your transaction nonce to be out of sync in both chains, and prevent you from having transactions automatically executed on both chains. See [Problem after withdrawal non hard fork ethereum](https://ethereum.stackexchange.com/questions/7482/problem-after-withdrawal-non-hard-fork-ethereum?noredirect=1&lq=1).
  - If your transactions are not being executed in both chains, your transaction nonce may be out of sync in both chains. If you still want to execute transactions on the OTHER chain, you will have to have your Ethereum node client synced to that OTHER chain.
- **If You Want To Send Pre-Hard-Forked ETC To An Exchange ETC Account**

  1. You can use your `support-hard-fork` or the `oppose-hard-fork` Ethereum node client to do this.
  2. On the exchange site, get the ETC deposit address.
  3. Use the `classicTransfer` method in `geth` or the **To Transfer Only On The Non-Hard-Forked Classic Chain** in **Ethereum Wallet**.
  4. Transfer a small test amount first. Check your ETH account on a blockchain explorer (e.g. http://etherscan.io/) and you should notice only a small amount deducted from your account for the cost of gas of the `SafeConditionalHFTransfer` contract sending back your ETH.
  5. You will have to wait a short while before the ETC transaction appears on your exchange ETC deposit address as the relaying adds a short delay to the transaction appearing on the ETC chain.

---

#### Update Aug 25 2016

[Ethereum Wallet and Mist Beta 0.8.2](https://github.com/ethereum/mist/releases/tag/0.8.2) now has replay prevention:

> **Replay prevention**
>
> We added an advanced feature to prevent your transactions on being replayed on other chains, like ethereum classic. This allows you either to prevent that transfer on happening on classic at all, or use that transaction to send the same amount to a different contract, like a newly created account or an exchange. If you want to fully separate all your transactions we recommend you create two new accounts, one for Ethereum proper and the other for Classic, and then move all your funds into them (remember that you need ether to move tokens), making sure that each account has 0 ether on the other chain - doing this once would prevent any future transaction from being replayed. To use this, use the "more options" button on the send page.
>
> This feature also supports splitting tokens, but it's very experimental and will not work on all tokens. Since all of this is done using a contract then first you need to allow that contract to move tokens in your behalf by clicking "Approve token transfer".
>
> As always, these features are **experimental and should be tested with small amounts first**. Although most transactions are replayed on both chains, some may not for multiple reasons. Also, some exchanges have issues receiving ether from a contract address - if that's your case, contact the exchange.
>
> We've also removed all Fork code from the Mist app, so if you want to use it Ether Classic you'll have to either download Classic Mist directly from their repository or use your own node as the backend for your wallet (both Ethereum Wallet and Mist can connect to any node) as you would do for a private network.

The replay protection contract can be found at [0x1ca4a86bba124426507d1ef67ad271cc5a02820a](http://etherscan.io/address/0x1ca4a86bba124426507d1ef67ad271cc5a02820a#code).

---

### Method 1 - Using `geth` And `SafeConditionalHFTransfer` Contract

Make sure that you are [running geth version 1.4.10](https://github.com/ethereum/go-ethereum/wiki/Building-Ethereum) or later. And run your geth commands with the --support-dao-fork option so that you are on the hard-forked blockchain. To transfer using the `transfer(...)` or `classicTransfer(...)` functions:

```
user@Kumquat:~$ geth console
// Allow chain to sync
var fromAccount = "{from account}";
var toAccount = "{to account}";
var amount = web3.toWei(1.123, "ether");
personal.unlockAccount(fromAccount, "{password}")

var safeConditionalHFTransferAddress = "0x1e143b2588705dfea63a17f2032ca123df995ce0";
var safeConditionalHFTransferABI = [{"constant":false,"inputs":[{"name":"to","type":"address"}],"name":"transfer","outputs":[],"type":"function"},{"constant":false,"inputs":[{"name":"to","type":"address"}],"name":"classicTransfer","outputs":[],"type":"function"},{"inputs":[],"type":"constructor"}];
var safeConditionalHFTransfer = eth.contract(safeConditionalHFTransferABI).at(safeConditionalHFTransferAddress);    

// WARNING - Run the next statement to transfer ETH on the hard-forked chain
// This will only cost some gas on the non-hard-forked ETC Classic chain
// Test with a small amount first
var transfer = safeConditionalHFTransfer.transfer(toAccount, {from: fromAccount, value: amount});
console.log(transfer);

// WARNING - Run the next statement to transfer ETC on the non-hard-forked Classic chain
// This will only cost some gas on the hard-forked ETH chain
// Test with a small amount first
var classicTransfer = safeConditionalHFTransfer.classicTransfer(toAccount, {from: fromAccount, value: amount});
console.log(classicTransfer);
```

---

### Method 2 - Using `geth` And `ReplaySafeSplitV2` Contract

Make sure that you are [running geth version 1.4.10](https://github.com/ethereum/go-ethereum/wiki/Building-Ethereum) or later. And run your geth commands with the --support-dao-fork option so that you are on the hard-forked blockchain. To transfer using the `split(...)` function:

```
user@Kumquat:~$ geth console
// Allow chain to sync
var fromAccount = "{from account}";
var toAccountFork = "{to account on forked chain}";
var toAccountNoFork = "{to account on non-forked chain}";
var amount = web3.toWei(1.123, "ether");
personal.unlockAccount(fromAccount, "{password}")

var replaySafeSplitV2Address = "0xaBbb6bEbFA05aA13e908EaA492Bd7a8343760477";
var replaySafeSplitV2ABI = [{"constant":false,"inputs":[{"name":"targetFork","type":"address"},{"name":"targetNoFork","type":"address"}],"name":"split","outputs":[{"name":"","type":"bool"}],"type":"function"}];
var replaySafeSplitV2 = eth.contract(replaySafeSplitV2ABI).at(replaySafeSplitV2Address);    

var transfer = replaySafeSplitV2.split(toAccountFork, toAccountNoFork, {from: fromAccount, value: amount});
console.log(transfer);
```

---

### Method 3 - Using Ethereum Wallet And `SafeConditionalHFTransfer` Contract

**Note that the `ReplaySafeSplitV2` contract below has more safety features built in.**

Make sure that you have downloaded [Ethereum Wallet 0.8.1](https://github.com/ethereum/mist/releases/tag/0.8.1) or later.

The first time you start Ethereum Wallet 0.8.1, select "Yes" to the question "Do you want to activate the chain in which funds linked to the exploit are restored to a contract where they can be withdrawn by The DAO token holders?". You have now made the choice to use the hard-forked Ethereum chain.

In Ethereum Wallet, select the CONTRACTS page in the top menu. Click on WATCH CONTRACT.

- Enter a CONTRACT NAME of `SafeConditionalHFTransfer`
- Enter a CONTRACT ADDRESS of `0x1e143b2588705dfea63a17f2032ca123df995ce0`
- Enter in JSON INTERFACE the following text `[{"constant":false,"inputs":[{"name":"to","type":"address"}],"name":"transfer","outputs":[],"type":"function"},{"constant":false,"inputs":[{"name":"to","type":"address"}],"name":"classicTransfer","outputs":[],"type":"function"},{"inputs":[],"type":"constructor"}]`
- Click OK. Your Watch Contract should look like:

[image]

#### To Transfer Only On The Hard-Forked Chain

This will transfer your ETH to the destination account on the hard-forked chain and will only cost you gas on the non-hard-forked Classic chain.

Select the CONTRACTS page in the top menu. Click on SAFECONDITIONALHFTRANSFER. On the right hand side of the page under WRITE TO CONTRACT, **Select function** `Transfer`. Enter your destination address on the hard-fork chain in the **To - address** field. In **Execute from**, select your account. Enter the number of ETH under the **Send ETHER** field. Click on the EXECUTE button, enter your password and confirm. Here is a screen image:

[image]

#### To Transfer Only On The Non-Hard-Forked Classic Chain

This will transfer your ETH to the destination account on the non-hard-forked Classic chain and will only cost you gas on the hard-forked chain.

Select the CONTRACTS page in the top menu. Click on SAFECONDITIONALHFTRANSFER. On the right hand side of the page under WRITE TO CONTRACT, **Select function** `Classic Transfer`. Enter your destination address on the non-hard-fork chain in the **To - address** field. In **Execute from**, select your account. Enter the number of ETH (ETC) under the **Send ETHER** field. Click on the EXECUTE button, enter your password and confirm. Here is a screen image:

[image]

---

### Method 4 - Using Ethereum Wallet And The `ReplaySafeSplitV2` Contract

**UPDATE 22:27 Sep 4 2016** This is a new safer version of `ReplaySafeSplit` as discussed by @chevdor on [thedao.slack.com/messages/general](https://thedao.slack.com/messages/general/) in [Safer version of the ReplaySafeSplit Smart Contract](https://medium.com/@chevdor/safer-version-of-the-replaysafesplit-smart-contract-a29c347e8a7#.z1b0tibrf). This new version has checks that the addresses you specify are not 0x0000...0000 before sending your ethers to the addresses. This section has been updated with the new contract details.

Make sure that you have downloaded [Ethereum Wallet 0.8.1](https://github.com/ethereum/mist/releases/tag/0.8.1) or later.

The first time you start Ethereum Wallet 0.8.1, select "Yes" to the question "Do you want to activate the chain in which funds linked to the exploit are restored to a contract where they can be withdrawn by The DAO token holders?". You have now made the choice to use the hard-forked Ethereum chain.

In Ethereum Wallet, select the CONTRACTS page in the top menu. Click on WATCH CONTRACT.

- Enter a CONTRACT NAME of `ReplaySafeSplitV2`
- <strike>Enter a CONTRACT ADDRESS of `0x8201...`</strike> (this old address was on the ETH chain only. **If you used this contract, please delete your Watch Contract and recreate the Watch Contract with the new address below.**)
- Enter a CONTRACT ADDRESS of `0xaBbb6bEbFA05aA13e908EaA492Bd7a8343760477`
- Enter in JSON INTERFACE the following text `[{"constant":false,"inputs":[{"name":"targetFork","type":"address"},{"name":"targetNoFork","type":"address"}],"name":"split","outputs":[{"name":"","type":"bool"}],"type":"function"}]`
- Click OK. Your Watch Contract should look like:

[image]

#### To Transfer

This will transfer your ETH to two accounts, the first being the destination account on the hard-forked chain and the second being the destination account on the non-hard-forked Classic chain.

Select the CONTRACTS page in the top menu. Click on REPLAYSAFESPLITV2. On the right hand side of the page under WRITE TO CONTRACT, **Select function** `Split`. Enter your destination address on the **hard-fork** chain in the **Target fork - address** field. Enter your destination address on the **non-hard-fork Classic** chain in the **Target no fork - address** field. In **Execute from**, select your account. Enter the number of ethers under the **Send ETHER** field. Click on the EXECUTE button, enter your password and confirm.

Here is a screen image:

[image]

---

### `SafeConditionalHFTransfer` Contract

**Note that the `ReplaySafeSplitV2` contract below has more safety features built in.**

Following is the source code for the [SafeConditionalHFTransfer contract](http://etherscan.io/address/0x1e143b2588705dfea63a17f2032ca123df995ce0#code) (suggested by `@shoraibit` 26/07/2016). This contract does not depend on the WithdrawDAO contract having a balance over 1,000,000 ethers in the future.

```
contract ClassicCheck {
    function isClassic() constant returns (bool isClassic);
}

contract SafeConditionalHFTransfer {        
    bool classic;

    function SafeConditionalHFTransfer() {
        classic = ClassicCheck(0x882fb4240f9a11e197923d0507de9a983ed69239).isClassic();
    }

    function classicTransfer(address to) {
        if (!classic) 
            msg.sender.send(msg.value);
        else
            to.send(msg.value);
    }

    function transfer(address to) {
        if (classic)
            msg.sender.send(msg.value);
        else
            to.send(msg.value);
    }            
}
```

This contract depends on the [ClassicCheck contract](http://etherscan.io/address/0x882fb4240f9a11e197923d0507de9a983ed69239#code):

```
contract ClassicCheck {   
    bool public classic;

    function ClassicCheck() {
        if (address(0xbf4ed7b27f1d666546e30d74d50d173d20bca754).balance > 1000000 ether)
            classic = false;
        else
            classic = true;
    }   

    function isClassic() constant returns (bool isClassic) {
        return classic;
    }
}
```

When the `SafeConditionalHFTransfer` contract was deployed, it used the `ClassicCheck` contract to determine whether the code was being deployed to the hard-forked or non-hard-forked chain. And this check was done when the [WithdrawDAO](http://etherscan.io/address/0xbf4ed7b27f1d666546e30d74d50d173d20bca754#code) had a balance over 1,000,000 . `SafeConditionalHFTransfer` **should always work** as it no longer has to check the balance of the WithdrawDAO balance.

---

### `ReplaySafeSplitV2` Contract

**UPDATE 22:27 Sep 4 2016** This is a new safer version of `ReplaySafeSplit` as discussed by @chevdor on [thedao.slack.com/messages/general](https://thedao.slack.com/messages/general/) in [Safer version of the ReplaySafeSplit Smart Contract](https://medium.com/@chevdor/safer-version-of-the-replaysafesplit-smart-contract-a29c347e8a7#.z1b0tibrf). This new version has checks that the addresses you specify are not `0x0000...0000` before sending your ethers to the addresses.

Following is the source code for the [ReplaySafeSplitV2 contract](http://etherscan.io/address/0xaBbb6bEbFA05aA13e908EaA492Bd7a8343760477#code):

```
contract RequiringFunds {
   modifier NeedEth () {
       if (msg.value <= 0 ) throw;
       _
   }
}

contract AmIOnTheFork {
   function forked() constant returns(bool);
}

contract ReplaySafeSplit is RequiringFunds {
   // address private constant oracleAddress = 0x8128B12cABc6043d94BD3C4d9B9455077Eb18807;    // testnet
   address private constant oracleAddress = 0x2bd2326c993dfaef84f696526064ff22eba5b362;   // mainnet

   // Fork oracle to use
   AmIOnTheFork amIOnTheFork = AmIOnTheFork(oracleAddress);

   // Splits the funds into 2 addresses
   function split(address targetFork, address targetNoFork) NeedEth returns(bool) {
       // The 2 checks are to ensure that users provide BOTH addresses
       // and prevent funds to be sent to 0x0 on one fork or the other.
       if (targetFork == 0) throw;
       if (targetNoFork == 0) throw;

       if (amIOnTheFork.forked()                   // if we are on the fork
           && targetFork.send(msg.value)) {        // send the ETH to the targetFork address
           return true;
       } else if (!amIOnTheFork.forked()           // if we are NOT on the fork
           && targetNoFork.send(msg.value)) {      // send the ETH to the targetNoFork address
           return true;
       }

       throw;                                      // don't accept value transfer, otherwise it would be trapped.
   }

   // Reject value transfers.
   function() {
       throw;
   }
}
```

Following is the VM code from the non-hard-forked Classic blockchain which matches the [verified VM code + source code](http://etherscan.io/address/0xaBbb6bEbFA05aA13e908EaA492Bd7a8343760477#code) on the hard-forked chain.

```
user@PussyWillow:~$ geth -exec 'eth.getCode("0xaBbb6bEbFA05aA13e908EaA492Bd7a8343760477")' attach
"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"
```

This contract depends on the [AmIOnTheFork contract](http://etherscan.io/address/0x2bd2326c993dfaef84f696526064ff22eba5b362#code):

```
contract AmIOnTheFork {
    bool public forked = false;
    address constant darkDAO = 0x304a554a310c7e546dfe434669c62820b7d83490;
    // Check the fork condition during creation of the contract.
    // This function should be called between block 1920000 and 1921200.
    // Approximately between 2016-07-20 12:00:00 UTC and 2016-07-20 17:00:00 UTC.
    // After that the status will be locked in.
    function update() {
        if (block.number >= 1920000 && block.number <= 1921200) {
            forked = darkDAO.balance < 3600000 ether;
        }
    }
    function() {
        throw;
    }
}
```

Comment: I was able to create a second Windows account and copy my chain data to different folder. Then started geth pointing at the Classic folder with the --datadir flag as well as the --oppose-dao-fork flag. So one Windows user account is on Classic and the other on Main net. I was able to use the above HFConditionalTranfer contract to send ether (started with just 1 initially) to a new account on Classic chain. I verified that at http://gastracker.io/ and https://etherscan.io/ initially while waiting for my Classic chain to fully sync. I then deposited ETC on Poloniex. So far so good.

Comment: I tried this with `--oppose-dao-fork` It works!

Comment: Have you tried tracing through live.ether.camp? Or if you are comfortable with it, could you post your TX hash?

Comment: My mistake it looks like etherscan didn't pick up on the internal tx, and i didn't wait long enough for the balance to update. All good. It works.

Comment: Couldn't someone create a contract on 0xb671c3883307cf05bb3dff77a9754e87b4347195 on the Ethereum Classic fork and somehow pool 10 million etc, so the check succeeds and the replay attack is enabled again?

Comment: @Fernando Yes, which is why it is wise to move your Ether on both chains to different addresses. This method let's you prevent replay attacks for the next few days or weeks so you can do this without any trouble... but definitely dispose of your pre-hardfork addresses if you care about replay attacks being possible when the DAO Refund address gooes under a million on the Main chain.

Comment: In your Method 1 code, `var classicTransfer = hfConditionalTransfer` is faulty because it still uses `hfConditionalTransfer` and not the safe version.

Comment: Thanks @ThomasKahle. I've now updated the code. Could you please check/test.

Comment: When I tested the contract it worked, (sending etc to poloniex, 1 at a time just to test twice) than I tried the total amount and it does not show up in gastracker. As f it didnt happen, i do get confirmations in Mist.

Comment: For Method 3, can you please explain how `ReplaySafeSplit` takes action on two blockchains? I don't get that part. I was expecting you'd have to run something twice, once each from a wallet pointing at one of the two blockchains.

Comment: `@mowliv`, transactions from the HF network are being relayed on the non-HF network currently and vice versa. I've updated the answer above.

Answer (score 2):

If you use a new client, such as Geth 1.5.3, it implements [EIP 155 Simple replay attack protection](https://github.com/ethereum/EIPs/issues/155) so that your ETH transactions should be safe from a replay attack on ETC.

Using Geth 1.5.3 (or later), you should create another account and move all your ETH to the new address.  Don't forget to backup this new account (and don't delete the old account since it has your ETC).

---

Extra step for the meantime since Geth 1.5.3 is very new: after the above, on the ETC chain move all ETC to a different address.  This will help ensure that you are indeed protected from replay attacks.