# Solidity contract - can the contract check what blockchain it is running on?

Tags: solidity, contract-development

Is it possible for me to add code to my contract to check the blockchain it is running on?

This is for security reasons as I only want to be running on the official Ethereum blockchain.

Answer (score 5):

See the conditional contracts listed in the question section of [How to conditionally send ethers to another account post-hard-fork to protect yourself from replay attacks](https://ethereum.stackexchange.com/questions/7396/how-to-conditionally-send-ethers-to-another-account-post-hard-fork-to-protect-yo) .

In particular, you can used the `ClassicCheck` or `AmIOnTheFork` contracts as an oracle to determine which blockchain you are running on.

And sample code to use the above contracts are in the `SafeConditionalHFTransfer` and `ReplaySafeSplit` contracts.