# Lost ether: wallet on some other chain

Tags: mist, synchronization, ethereum-wallet-dapp, forks, pending-transactions

Yesterday I decided to move my Ethereum coins to my coinbase account from my PC based Ether wallet from Ethereum.org . I had 107ish coins. I sent 1.2 to my coinbase address as a test and they arrived with no issues.

I then repeated the same process with the remaining 105 and the coins left my wallet but never arrived at my coinbase wallet. I have looked at the blockchain to try to find my transaction but the blockchain says the transactions never happened and my wallet still has a balance of 104 coins however my wallet on my pc shows my balance as 0.0.

Need help please.

https://etherscan.io/address/0x108091B54A547e9334FEAA72F59ec47272654dea

Thanks

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because, it is not going to help any future visitors and this is very specific to the user and what he does with it.

Comment: This is an issue with synching to the wrong chain and would most likely affect quite a number of users for the short-to-medium term.

Comment: I'm going to try to improve the title and feel free to make it more accurate.

Answer (score 3):

Your coins seem to be in your account on the public blockchain explorer, so I don't think you have to worry.

The next step is to work out what has happened in your local wallet. Presumably you are using the Ethereum Wallet. Check the block number (like 2,105,732 currently) on the top of your Ethereum Wallet screen. This should match the latest block in [https://etherscan.io](https://etherscan.io/). If your block numbers are not matching, you may be on the non-hard-forked Classic chain. And looking at the Classic chain explorer, your 105.632 ETC transaction did occur. See https://etcchain.com/addr/0x108091b54a547e9334feaa72f59ec47272654dea.

I suspect that your Ethereum Wallet is synced to the non-hard-forked Classic chain.

Check the menu Develop -> "The DAO" Fork. You probably have "Don't Support DAO Fork" selected. Change this to "Support DAO Fork". You will have to wait until your blockchain re-syncs again and this will take a while.

You should check out [How to conditionally send ethers to another account post-hard-fork to protect yourself from replay attacks](https://ethereum.stackexchange.com/questions/7396/how-to-conditionally-send-ethers-to-another-account-post-hard-fork-to-protect-yo) as you could accidentally transfer your coins to the wrong address if you are not careful.

You will also have to have [Ethereum Wallet v0.8.1](https://github.com/ethereum/mist/releases/tag/0.8.1) or above with geth 1.4.10 or later.

---

#### Response to questions in comments

**Q** When I make the switch over to the new blockchain will my wallet rebroadcast the same transaction again but on the new blockchain?

**A** It should not. The transaction was broadcasted by the Ethereum Wallet to the Classic network and some nodes on the Classic network may or may not relay the transaction to the hard-forked network.

**Q** Will this not mean that the same transaction is in two different block on both chains or can my wallet edit a block from the past?

**A** The same transaction can be in two different blocks on both chains. Your wallet cannot edit a block from the past.

**Q** I have clicked the link to view my transaction on the old blockchain however the link does not work as the website is down. Is there another website that allows me to check my transaction? I wanted to check I sent the coins to the correct address? -> 0x6b163A9A8804d2e8F76F7FdC4EaD042393631481

**A** I've updated the link to a work Classic block explorer.

**Q** Also, what chain is dominant? If I have coins in my wallet on the new chain and no coins in my wallet on the old chain what chain wins? What chain is dominant?

**A** From http://fork.ethstats.net/, the Classic chain has ~ 14% the hashpower of the hard-forked chain. The dominant chain does not depend on the coins in your wallet.

[image]

**Q** @BokkyPooBah I have one more question that has come into my head. The first transaction appeared on both blockchains both new and old. The second transaction appeared on only the old. I take it that the chains talk to each other to update each other. Is this not a glitch in the way they talk to each other as it seems odd that the first transaction would get synced and the second would not. etherscan.io/address/0x108091B54A547e9334FEAA72F59ec47272654‌​dea

**A** Some nodes on the network have been configured to re-broadcast the transactions from one network to the other. From my past transactions, the re-broadcasted transactions appear on the other network with a delay of up to tens of minutes OR not at all.

Comment: I had a similar problem and it turned out to be exactly what @BokkyPooBah described. When you send ether, regardless of which fork you're on, it can broadcast to the network and execute on both forks at once.

Comment: Hi, thank you for your answer. Yes you are right I am on the old block chain. I will make the switch now. However have some more questions as I am a newbie to Ethereium.

Comment: When I make the switch over to the new blockchain will my wallet rebroadcast the same transaction again but on the new blockchain? Will this not mean that the same transaction is in two different block on both chains or can my wallet edit a block from the past?

I have clicked the link to view my transaction on the old blockchain however the link does not work as the website is down. Is there another website that allows me to check my transaction? I wanted to check I sent the coins to the correct address? -> 0x6b163A9A8804d2e8F76F7FdC4EaD042393631481

Comment: Also, what chain is dominant? If I have coins in my wallet on the new chain  and no coins in my wallet on the old chain what chain wins? What chain is dominant?

Comment: Sorry @BokkyPooBah I have replied to your reply but I have forgotten to put your name in the comments above. Please can you have a look and let me know. I want to say thank you for all your help. :)

Comment: @BokkyPooBah I have one more question that has come into my head. The first transaction appeared on both blockchains both new and old. The second transaction appeared on only the old. I take it that the chains talk to each other to update each other. Is this not a glitch in the way they talk to each other as it seems odd that the first transaction would get synced and the second would not.  https://etherscan.io/address/0x108091B54A547e9334FEAA72F59ec47272654dea

Comment: I've updated my answer to try to address your questions above.

Answer (score 1):

Have you tried using myetherwallet.com and entering your json key and password and then since you were on the old unforked chain you should have had ETH and ETC ~ 107 ish of each, the ETC can be transferred to an exchange that accepts them and then keep them or sell them (your preference), once you point the client(your address) and enter the key and password you can split the eth and etc to accomplish this task and send to coinbase and wherever else...

Answer (score 0):

I just want to say that I tried a few times and in the end I copied my wallet key to usb and then created a new user on my windows computer. I then downloaded the new version of the wallet program and extracted it to a folder on my desktop. I finally synced with the new chain from the start.

I now have all my ETH back and have sent them to Coinbase.

So in sort my solution was. Copy wallet key, create new windows use, extract new copy of wallet program to folder on my desktop and sync to new chain from the start. Tada!

Thanks to everyone for help.