# How to transfer to wallet

Tags: wallets

I have setup 3 rig's With GPU mining and I'm currently averaging around 25 - 30  MH/s with my test setup. The rig is setup using QTminer and I can see that ETH is coming in to my account and I have tried to do a transfer of 0.2 ETH from ethermine that was successfull as I see the amount in my balance.  (https://www.etherchain.org/account/0x9003c372d2e1b1e8b4d27ecf415bf70c9739bfce)

Now, here is the question.
When I use geth or the "etherium wallet" I get a Balance of 0.
When I I og to the etherchain (or any other) i get the correct Balance.
As far as i can see the wallet and Geth is synced.

can anyone help me out here with some tips on how to fix this, and how to transfer funds to my wallet after I this is fixed.

Geth info: 
Version: 1.4.10-stable
Protocol Versions: [63 62]
Network Id: 1
Go Version: go1.6.2
OS: windows
GOPATH=
GOROOT=c:\go

Etherium wallet is Version 0.8.1

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How to send ether to a cold storage account?](http://ethereum.stackexchange.com/questions/524/how-to-send-ether-to-a-cold-storage-account)

Comment: You have most likely synced to the wrong Classic chain. See http://ethereum.stackexchange.com/questions/8171/lost-105-ether-help for syncing to the hard-forked chain in Ethereum Wallet. To sync to the hard-forked chain in `geth`, use the command `geth --support-dao-fork console`.