# My ethereum mist walled didn't receive my ether

Tags: transactions

I have sent 10 ETH to my Mist wallet a week ago.. the wallet is synched, there is still 0 ETH balance on it... I am worried now, what should I do? Is my money lost? What is going on, please help.. thank you[image]

Comment: Check out http://ethereum.stackexchange.com/questions/8171/lost-ether-wallet-on-some-other-chain . You may be on the Ethereum Classic chain.