# When Eth Classic was forked off, did the people who held Ether suddenly hold an identical sum in two currencies?

Tags: ethereum-classic, blockchain-fork

I'm having a hard time understanding forks. What happened to the transactions in the blockchain before block 1'920'000? Are they present in both resulting blockchains, i.e. everybody then had two wallets filled with an identical amount of each currency?

- If not, how was it solved instead?
- If yes, did the resulting two tokens together have the value of one previous token, or did everybody suddenly get double rich?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The chains were forked at block 1,920,000 so they have in common the previous blocks. At that block existing balances were duplicated in both chains. There were contracts that were deployed in order to prevent transaction replaying, see here for some details [How to conditionally send ethers to another account post-hard-fork to protect yourself from replay attacks](https://ethereum.stackexchange.com/questions/7396/how-to-conditionally-send-ethers-to-another-account-post-hard-fork-to-protect-yo).

Some people didn't expect ETC to survive and its initial price was lower than ETH.