# What happened with the presale ether after the fork?

Tags: mist, ether, ethereum-classic, presale, import

I have never accessed my presale ether. As I understand, a major fork occurred some time ago. I have some confusion regarding the current situation.

1. What will happen to my ether?
2. Do I get both ETC and ETH?
3. I read that I can use Mist to access the wallet. Are there any precautions that I should take with respect to the fork?

EDIT:

I can't comment so I'll add it here. To import/recover my ether and split it into ETC/ETH do I need to do it on both chains or which one?

Comment: For the edited part, please read the various answers to your third question and have a reasonable understanding of the approach you want to do (some approaches are safe doing on a single chain).

Answer (score 3):

1. The Ether will still be in your Ether address.
2. Yes, you will have both ETC and ETH.  If there are any other forks that use the genesis block from the Ethereum presale, you will have all those Ether too.
3. You may want to "split" your ETC and ETH to different addresses to avoid replay attacks: [this](https://ethereum.stackexchange.com/questions/7267/how-to-prevent-a-replay-attack-between-two-competing-chains) leads to a number of options for doing so.