# Acquired Ether in the presale. Using Mist, how do I split into ETH and ETC?

Tags: mist, ethereum-classic

Acquired Ether in the presale. Using Mist, transferred ETH into an account. How do I split into ETH and ETC? Want to take the ETC to an exchange. Thx.

Answer (score 1):

this might be what you are looking for:

https://theethereum.wiki/w/index.php/The_DAO_Refunds

Answer (score 1):

Assuming Mist doesn't deal with [EIP155](https://github.com/ethereum/EIPs/issues/155) which makes your transactions appear on only one of the Ethereum blockchain or the Ethereum Classic blockchain (depending on which you choose), and assuming you do now have ETC (you can check your balance using a blockchain explorer for [ETH](https://etherscan.io) and [ETC](https://etcchain.com)) you have at least two options:

- Import or send your funds to a wallet that supports EIP155 such as recent versions of geth and Parity, ensuring that you use the same address on both chains. Importing avoids an extra fee for gas (transaction price). Then load your EIP155-supporting wallet and send your ETC to an exchange.
- Use the [splitter contract](https://ethereum.stackexchange.com/questions/7267/how-to-prevent-a-replay-attack-between-two-competing-chains/10307#10307) to send your ether to two different addresses -- one on the ETH chain and one on the ETC chain. You can *probably* list the exchange deposit address as the recipient of the ETC transfer without issue to avoid paying for even more gas.

In all cases, you should send a small amount of ether as a test and ensure that the transaction only appears on the chain you expect. That being said, the more reputable exchanges might be able to help you if you ended up sending a transaction on both chains to the same address, but I wouldn't count on it.

Comment: lungj, thank you for your response, info and links very helpful. Not sure I have enough info to figure out how to move forward, perhaps you can help.

Comment: Downloaded Mist v0.8.10
Loaded presale json file to Mist Wallet, Main Account (Etherbase)
Created new account in same Mist Wallet, ETH Deposit Account (Account 2)

Utilized ReplaySafeSplitV2 to moved most ETH to ETH Deposit Account (Account 2)

Verified the following on gastracker.io
Main Account (Etherbase) contains all my ETC (10 ETC) and a portion of my ETH (0.8 ETH)
ETH Deposit Account (Account 2) contains the remainder of my ETH (9.1 ETH) after gas expense.

Still not able to send my ETC to an exchange, which is the goal. Thx in advance for your assist!

Comment: I'm not quite sure I followed what happened here. Gastracker.io only looks at ETC. What should happen is you have your ETH-ETC account (A). You create a pure ETH account (B) and a pure ETC account (C). Using the splitter contract, you send _x_ eth from A to the contract, providing accounts B and C. Afterwards, account A should have _x_ less ETH and ETC. Account B should have _x_ more ETH and 0 ETC (or not be seen on the ETC chain). Account C should have _x_ more ETC and 0 ETH (or not be seen on the ETH chain).

Comment: All accounts A, B and C in the same Mist wallet, yes?

Comment: That might work, but I was thinking that the accounts are created on separate installations/configurations of Mist (sorry, I only briefly used Mist -- can't provide more details), each synchronized to a different blockchain (ETH, ETC).