# Blockchain sync lost after restarting geth?

Tags: go-ethereum

I'm new to mining ethereum so this may be a very basic question.

I ran geth in attempt to sync the blockchain on my machine as follows

```
geth --rpc --fast --cache=2048
```

After letting it spin for about a day I ran `get attach` and saw the following

```
> web3.eth.syncing
{
  currentBlock: 3274586,
  highestBlock: 3275837,
  ...
}
```

I then restarted geth, with the intention of not passing in the `fast` flag and allowing geth to continue syncing the blockchain normally so that I could start to mine. However when running `geth attach` and checking the value of `web3.eth.syncing` I saw the the following

```
{
  currentBlock: 580,
  highestBlock: 1707213,
  ...
}
```

Is there some way to start geth with the blockchain from my initial sync, or do I have a misunderstanding of how geth is meant to be used?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

### Because `geth --fast` will not download the entire blocks

> Instead of processing the entire Blockchain one link at a time, and replay all transactions that ever happened in history, fast syncing downloads the transaction receipts along the blocks, and pulls an entire recent state database.

When you remove `--fast` flag, the chain will start syncing all the blocks from very beginning.

Comment: Thank you for your answer. In order to mitigate having to replay all transactions each time geth is run, is it better to run geth without the `--fast` flag and allow the blockchain to sync normally?

Comment: @James Not really. `replay all transactions each time geth is run` will not be the case. It is just to allow you to get the necessary blocks to do the txn. `replay attack` is explained here http://ethereum.stackexchange.com/q/26/259